Open a React Native Android Application within my Android native application and send data to the React Native module component?
How can we achieve opening a React Native Android app within my native Android Application which makes the other application (React Native Application) looks like it belongs to the same main application package (Android Studio Package)? I also want to send and receive data back on onBackPress event?
I have followed below Medium URL but I am unable to achieve the desired behaviour.
Medium URL
Getting below error after integrating all the Gradle files and syncing the Android studio project
"Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'node'' finished with non-zero exit value 1"
